# How to Query Individuals using OWL DL Query in Protege 4?

Tags: ontology, protege4, dlquery

How do I query individulas in my ontology, here is a description of what I would like to do (similar to SQL queries):

I have three classes (components, features, and polarity). The polarity value can be positive_polarity or negative_polarity, both are subclasses of polarity.

- a_component hasFeature a_Feature
- a_Feautre hasPolarity a_Polarity

I would like to list all components which have a positive_polarity value.

How can this be achieved using the DL Query tab in protege 4?

Answer (score 2):

```
component that hasFeature some (feature that hasPolarity some negative_polarity)
```

provided that there's a feature in there somewhere asserted as type:

```
feature that hasPolarity some negative_polarity
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Taveren, but this query displays features, and not components. I want to display the components in the individuals list.

Comment: Ok had another go at it, but would need to see a mock up of the ontology to help any further. HTH